# transforming a regex match to upper case using linux

Tags: regex, linux, uppercase

I would like to search for the following regex: "[ag][ag]aag[acg]" and transform only the whole match to uppercase but not individual search for a or g. 
i tried sed 'y/[ag][ag]aag[acg]/[AG][AG]AAG[ACG]/' but that transforms individual search for lowercase a or g to upper case A or G. I want to only transform when it found matches to the whole sequence.

Greatly appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
sed 's/\([ag][ag]aag[acg]\)/\U\1/' input
```

which finds a match to `[ag][ag]aag[acg]` and captures this match `\(...\)`. It then replaces the match with its upper-cased version `\U\1`.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. It substitute the matches to UU. Is there a another way? Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

The sed statement @perreal posted works. are you sure you are using it correctly?

Contents of testsed = agaaga

sed 's/([ag][ag]aag[acg])/\U\1/' testsed

AGAAGA